# Orchestration methodologies

Tags: orchestration

A job posting I am interested in calls for "full knowledge of orchestration methodologies".

Is there a recognized list of such methodologies? Or is it another name for specific orchestration algorithms or properties like synchronous/asynchronous, transactional, long-running etc.?

Answer (score 0):

orchestration  means "An arrangement of events that attempts to achieve a maximum effect" by meaning  "full knowledge of orchestration methodologies" they would like to ask whether you know the way to perform such events that produces the maximum result they want.

OR this could be A programming model for the orchestration of Web services